# php function not seeing value of parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a php function in codeignter set up to run a query based on all the values it is given. By default, it's set up in my model like so:

```
function get_news($page=0, $limit=4, $offset=0, $name=0) {
    if($name == 0) {
        $query = $this->db->get('table', $limit, $offset);
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('name'=>''.$name.''), $limit, $offset);
    }
}
```

However when I pass a value for $name in my controller, it runs the query for $name==0

```
$name = "Bob";
$this->News_model->get_news($page=0, $limit=3, $offset=0, $name);
```

Any idea why the $name value isn't going through?

Comment: Don't call the function using `$this->News_model->get_news($page=0, $limit=3, $offset=0, $name);`.... use `$this->News_model->get_news(0, =3, 0, $name);`.... but what is the concatenation in `array('name'=>''.$name.''), ` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

Model

```
function get_news($page=0, $limit=4, $offset=0, $name=0) {
  if($name == 0) {
    $query = $this->db->get('table', $limit, $offset);
  } else {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('name'=>$name), $limit, $offset);
  }
}
```

use

```
$name = "Bob";
$this->News_model->get_news(0, 3, 0, $name);
```